# ubuntu 16.04 when switch from tty1 back to tty7 (GUI), sometimes I need login again

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Sometimes, When I press ctrl+alt+f7 switch from tty1 back to GUI env, the screen show the previous one but immediately become black then show a login screen, I need login again, How can I avoid this.

Comment: You may do this kind of question on https://askubuntu.com/. A more proper site for this.

Comment: thanks, I will ask on  askubuntu.com